# Password visible using DevicePolicyManager

Tags: android, device-policy-manager

Am developing a sample application for some administration activities. I need to know how to make password visible using Device Policy Manager. Give me a sample code or else suggest me any ways to handle it.

Comment: I too facing the similar issue? Did you find the solution means? Help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visible password can be read and write using the below piece of code:
int visiblePassword = Settings.System.getInt(
                this.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD, 1);

```
     if(visiblePassword==0){
         Settings.System.putInt(
                    this.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.TEXT_SHOW_PASSWORD, 1);

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that would be impossible... Passwords should not be available as plain text after input.

Comment: Hi, Its no need to be as plain text. While entering a letter it have to show the letter and then it can be * or .(dot) Actually there is an visible password option in security settings of device for my scenario. I've to control that too using Device Policy Manager. Can you help me?